# Empty Scope when rotating the device ionic

Tags: android, ios, ajax, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on a mobile app using ionic, and I need to handle the view when the device is rotated, so I used this code to detect the screen with and update the view:

```
$scope.products = [];
$rootScope.dato = [];

ProductsService.getProductsFromCategory($scope.category_id).then(function(data){
  $rootScope.dato = data.data.products;
  load_data($rootScope.dato);
  console.log("############# xxxxdxxxdxxxxdxxxxd ##############" +JSON.stringify($rootScope.dato));
  $ionicLoading.hide();
});

$scope.calculateDimensions = function(gesture) {
  console.log("############# Calculate produit ##############" +JSON.stringify($rootScope.dato));
  $scope.dev_width = $window.innerWidth;
  $scope.dev_height = $window.innerHeight;
  $scope.devider = parseInt($scope.dev_width / 150);
}

angular.element($window).bind('resize', function(){
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    console.log("############# test Calculate produit ##############" +JSON.stringify($rootScope.dato));
    load_data($rootScope.dato);
  })       
});

function load_data(products) {
  $scope.calculateDimensions(); 
  console.log("############# befir called ##############" +JSON.stringify(products));

  $scope.products = [];
  while (products.length) {
      $scope.products.push(products.splice(0, $scope.devider))
  }
  console.log("############# after called ##############" +JSON.stringify($scope.products));
  console.log("############# befir called ##############" +JSON.stringify($rootScope.dato));
}
```

First time my $scope.data contains a json array but when I rotate a device my $scope.data shows me an empty array [].

Thanks.

Comment: where from your `$scope.data` is coming ?? I gues that all content gets refresh on rotate, and then it's set up to null somehow

Comment: $scope.data come from an http service.

Comment: yeah, but your service runs only once as a singleton and probably your `$scope.data` is not there when you rotate device, are you initializing `$scope.data = []` somewhere ?? , maybe try to use $rootScope ??

Comment: check my edit i just add the complet code